# Javascript require caching

Tags: javascript, caching, require

For a small stateless API I'm designing, I need a very simple i18n tool. I will manage less than 30 strings in 2 languages, no more.

I decided to write a very simple i18n tool:

```js
exports.i18nString = function (language, stringID) {
    try {
        var dictionary = require(`./${language}.json`)

        if (Array.isArray(dictionary[stringID])) {
            return dictionary[stringID][Math.floor(Math.random() * dictionary[stringID].length)];
        }
        return dictionary[stringID];
    } catch(error) {

    }
    return "";
}
```

An example JSON dictionary:

```
{
    "example": "This is an example",
    "multi": [
        "Choice 1",
        "Choice 2",
        "Choice 3"
    ]
}
```

It works perfectly and really fits my needs. One thing bothers me though: the presence of a `require` in the function I'm calling each time in need a string.

I'm a beginner in Js, but I know that `require` opens the file, reads its content and evaluates it. But I don't know if Js is smart enough to keep file's content in cache for subsequent calls. If it's the case, then my code is ok. If it's not, I might face performance issues.

Can you guys enlight me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an answer while searching at random.

Here's the thing: Node.js *does* cache every file, as explained [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching):

*Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This means (among other things) that every call to `require('foo')` will get exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same file.
Provided `require.cache` is not modified, multiple calls to `require('foo')` will not cause the module code to be executed multiple times.*